# Creating a new DataFrame using the output of a list obtained from an existing DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, nested-lists

Using the .tolist() function, I created a list 'genrelist'.

```
genrelist = movies_1000.Genre.str.split().tolist()
print(genrelist)
```

Pasting the output that I got:-

```
[['Action,Crime,Drama'], ['Action,Adventure,Sci-Fi'], 
['Action,Biography,Drama'], ['Adventure,Drama,Sci-Fi'], 
['Animation,Drama,Fantasy'], ['Biography,Comedy,Drama'], 
['Drama,Music'], ['Drama,Mystery,Sci-Fi'], ['Crime,Drama,Thriller'], 
['Drama,Family,Music'], ['Action,Thriller'], ['Drama,Thriller'], 
['Animation,Adventure,Family'], ['Comedy,Drama'], 
['Animation,Drama,Romance']]
```

I then used the following function to obtain unique items from this nested list.

```
genrecount = Counter()
for arr in genrelist:
    genrecount.update(arr[0].split(','))

print(genrecount)
```

Pasting the output that I got:-

```
Counter({'Drama': 12, 'Action': 4, 'Adventure': 3, 'Sci-Fi': 3, 
'Animation': 3, 'Thriller': 3, 'Crime': 2, 'Biography': 2, 'Comedy': 
2, 'Music': 2, 'Family': 2, 'Fantasy': 1, 'Mystery': 1, 'Romance': 
1})
```

I'd like to use the output obtained above to create a new DataFrame. Hence I used the following:-

```
genre_df = pd.DataFrame(genrecount.items())
```

Pasting the error that I got:-

```
ValueError: DataFrame constructor not properly called!
```

Also tried without the .items as follows:-

```
genre_df = pd.DataFrame(genrecount.items())
```

Pasting the error that I got:-

```
ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index
```

So I am trying to create a new DataFrame from the output of genrecount obtained above. Please advice as to what can be used to obtain the desired output and how to label the columns appropriately as Genre and Count. I believe that the word Counter in the output of genrecount is creating all the fuss. But don't know how to correct it.

Also need to understand how would the logic change, if my input genrelist had some spaces in between the string as follows:

```
[['Action',' Crime','  Drama'], ['Action','  Adventure','Sci-Fi'], 
['  Action',' Biography','Drama'], ['Adventure','Drama',' Sci-Fi'], 
['Animation','Drama','Fantasy'], ['Biography',' Comedy',' Drama'], 
['Drama','   Music   '], ['Drama','Mystery','  Sci-Fi'], 
['Crime  ','Drama',' Thriller'], ['Drama', ' Family ' ,' Music'], 
['Action', 'Thriller'], ['Drama',' Thriller'], 
['Animation',' Adventure',' Family'], ['Comedy',' Drama'], 
['Animation',' Drama',' Romance']]
```

Thanks in advance..!

Comment: You could try `df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(genrecount.items())`

Comment: @Plasma - It didn't work as I mentioned below. And any suggestions around the second list that I mentioned with leading and trailing spaces?

Comment: You can get rid of the white-space by `strip()`-ing your strings before counting, e.g. by replacing `genrecount.update(arr[0].split(','))` with `genrecount.update(map(str.strip, arr[0].split(",")))` in your loop. I'm honestly not sure why you're still having the constructor error, though.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in my comment, you can use the `from_dict()` function, as `Counter` is a subclass of dicts. Here's a complete example:

```
import pandas as pd
from collections import Counter

genrecount = Counter({'Drama': 12, 'Action': 4, 'Adventure': 3, 'Sci-Fi': 3, 'Animation': 3, 'Thriller': 3, 'Crime': 2, 'Biography': 2, 'Comedy': 2, 'Music': 2, 'Family': 2, 'Fantasy': 1, 'Mystery': 1, 'Romance': 1})

genre_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(genrecount.items())
genre_df.columns = ["genre", "count"]

print genre_df
```

Output:

```
        genre  count
0     Mystery      1
1     Romance      1
2      Sci-Fi      3
3      Family      2
4   Biography      2
5       Crime      2
6       Drama     12
7     Fantasy      1
8   Animation      3
9       Music      2
10  Adventure      3
11     Action      4
12     Comedy      2
13   Thriller      3
```

Comment: Am still getting the same error: 
ValueError: DataFrame constructor not properly called!

Comment: ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-25-004e498df5fb> in <module>()
      7     genrecount.update(arr[0].split(','))
      8 
----> 9 genre_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(genrecount.items())
     10 genre_df.columns = ["genre", "count"]
     11

Comment: ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in from_dict(cls, data, orient, dtype, columns)
    983             raise ValueError('only recognize index or columns for orient')
    984 
--> 985         return cls(data, index=index, columns=columns, dtype=dtype)
    986 
    987     def to_dict(self, orient='dict', into=dict):

Comment: ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in __init__(self, data, index, columns, dtype, copy)
    420                                          dtype=values.dtype, copy=False)
    421             else:
--> 422                 raise ValueError('DataFrame constructor not properly called!')
    423 
    424         NDFrame.__init__(self, mgr, fastpath=True)

ValueError: DataFrame constructor not properly called!

Comment: That's odd. Does ´type(genrecount)´ print `<class 'collections.Counter'>`? And what version of pandas are you using?

Comment: type(genrecount) gave me collections.Counter

Comment: pd.__version__ is '0.23.0'

Comment: I'm not sure why it doesn't work for you. Works fine for me locally, and on this repl: https://repl.it/repls/DearLowestMass